# Can I use virtualbox with a 64 Bit image in a 32 bit host

Tags: virtualbox

I have Virtualbox 4.1.20 in Ubuntu 12.04 32 Bit (With PAE) and I want to run Ubuntu Server 64 Bit on the Guest. Is this possible?. I ask since I get the following warning:

[image]

I want to make sure that there is no option to "emulate" this. I have a 64 bit CPU that supports virtualization. The Intel DZ68DB motherboard with an Intel I7 2600 CPU.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Virtualbox supports running a 64-bit guest VM on a 32-bit physical host, but there are some requirements and other caveats:

[From the manual:](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html)

VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are met:

- You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see the section called [“Hardware vs. software virtualization”](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt)).
- You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
- If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM. **Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request.**

> - Warning:
> - On any host, *you should enable the I/O APIC* for virtual machines that you intend to use in 64-bit mode. This is especially true for 64-bit Windows VMs. See the section called [“"Advanced" tab”](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-general-advanced). In addition, for 64-bit Windows guests, you should make sure that the VM uses the Intel networking device, since there is no 64-bit driver support for the AMD PCNet card; see the section called [“Virtual networking hardware”](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#nichardware).

Comment: You know what I forgot, the point about "you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM". I was reusing the 32 Bit Ubuntu. Thanks friend.

Comment: "You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support" On the host?  A 32-bit host with a 64-bit processor?

Comment: @Alex 64-bit host hardware with a 32-bit host OS installed on it.