# How can I emulate an amd64 system on an i386 system?

Tags: virtualization, qemu

Is there a way to use virtualization to emulate an amd64 system on a system running with an i386 CPU, or with an amd64 capable CPU running an i386 kernel?

I tried using virtual-manager to set up an amd64 qemu-kvm system on my amd64 compatible Turon X2 system (with an i386 installation) but I got a complaint that my computer was an i686.

How can I do this with my computer without reinstalling and how can others with i386 hardware do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use KVM on a 32bit host to emulate 64bit machine, see this:

- http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/FAQ#Can_KVM_run_a_32-bit_guest_on_a_64-bit_host.3F_What_about_PAE.3F

[QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) allows you to do it using x86_64 target with `--no-kvm`, see this:

- http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-945502-start-0.html

However, emulating without kvm is rather slow, see e.g. these for more info:

- https://superuser.com/questions/630860/64-bit-guest-on-a-32-bit-host
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124/can-i-run-a-64-bit-vmware-image-on-a-32-bit-machine

Hope this helps.

Comment: "rather slow" is a bit of an understatement ;)

Comment: @psusi :) Awww, come on - [Тетрис](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_ev_IHPwkU) works just fine! ;)

Comment: Virtual Box can do this too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/180761/can-i-use-virtualbox-with-a-64-bit-image-in-a-32-bit-host

Comment: Thanks @Takkat - I think QEMU supports this without restrictions (i.e. need a 64-bit CPU, etc.) though. Hence the slowness...