# use *only some* 64-bit packages on 32-bit Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

This is [not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one) a question about switching *every* one of my packages, or `ubuntu-desktop` (which I don't even use) to 64-bit.

I want to build *just a couple* programs in 64-bit. Is the answer different to the linked one above?

Comment: @kos sorry for the unclarity. I compile R from source rather than using the `apt-get` packages.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit and 64-bit refer to the size of memory registers in a computer's CPU. How do you suppose a 32-bit kernel should do that?

- A 32-bit kernel can run 32-bit software.
- A 64-bit kernel can run 64-bit software and 32-bit software.

You need a 64-bit kernel to run 64-bit software.

The only way to use 64-bit software on a 32-bit system is with virtualization: install a 64-bit system into vBox or VmWare but that requires some support from your BIOS (You need enable **Intel (R) Virtualization Technology** and **Intel (R) VT-d**. More on this here: [Can I use virtualbox with a 64 Bit image in a 32 bit host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180761/can-i-use-virtualbox-with-a-64-bit-image-in-a-32-bit-host) ).