# ubuntu 64 bit installation on VMWare?

Tags: 14.04, windows, vmware

In my laptop have a Windows 7 ultimate 32-bit operating system and

Intel(R)core (TM) i5-2430 M cpu @ 240 Ghz procesor and 8 Gb RAM but

I want to install the Ubuntu 64 bit on my Vmware workstation using ISO file.

Is it possible ???

Comment: Don't know about VMware but Virtualbox allows it. Answer here [@AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180761/can-i-use-virtualbox-with-a-64-bit-image-in-a-32-bit-host).

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124/can-i-run-a-64-bit-vmware-image-on-a-32-bit-machine).