# Why do I get this error and what version will work?

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I have downloaded virtualbox 5.1.6. All went just fine. I am now trying to load Linux. I continue to get an error "This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU."
My system:4GB RAM 
ATI Radeon HD 5670 1GB 
AMD Athlon II X2 250
I have tried several different downloads including the 32 bit version and still get this error. Each time I have removed the created box and started with a new one. I'm trying to take an online course to become familiar with Linux. I am not looking to create a dual boot or new OS. I'm a beginner when it comes to Linux so any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: [Can I use virtualbox with a 64 Bit image in a 32 bit host](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180761/can-i-use-virtualbox-with-a-64-bit-image-in-a-32-bit-host)

Comment: What is the host OS?

Comment: Your host OS is probably 32Bit and you are trying to install 64bit ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar and I had to go into bios and make sure virtualization was turned on and secure compute was turned off.  My system is Intel not AMD so I am not sure if you have the same options.